# What Level Adjustment does a Dhampir have?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ravenloft, character-templates

Looking in Denizens of Dread page 55, I cannot seems to find an LA entry, while this is clearly presented as a usable template (and looking at the gains from the template, I don't think "No LA" is applicable here). I've been looking on the internet, and people seem a bit torn. Some say +1, some say +2, and both of these options still seem rather low to me.

Do I need new glasses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample human fighter dhampir has a Level Adjustment of +8. This should be the LA for any dhampir character.

Comment: Dang. I had hoped for something more... Playable. Ah well, maybe I can discuss something with the DM.

Comment: Lack of errata in the only thing close to an [errata document](http://fraternityofshadows.com/TheVault/RL_Errata.html) leads me to agree.